# Найти вхождение подстроки в строку на Си

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, строки, циклы

подскажите пожалуйста: есть два массива символов которые вводятся пользователем, нужно посимвольно их проверить и найти подстроку в строке без использования strstr, вывести индекс первого вхождения, никак не могу додуматься до нужного условия для цикла.

вот код того что готово, нужно вроде только в циклы правильное условие:

```
 int main()
{
    char str1[SIZE], str2[SIZE]; // объявляем массивы.

    printf("Input string: ");
    fill_str(str1); // вызываем функцию заполнения для первого массива(строка).

    printf("Input pattern: ");
    fill_str(str2); // вызываем функцию заполнения для второго массива(подстрока).

    print_str(find_str(str1, str2)); // функция вывода с аргументом возвращаемого значения из функции сравнения строк.

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void fill_str(char str1[]) // заполнение массива.
{
    gets(str1); // получаем ввод пользователя для заполнения массива
}

int find_str(char str1[], char str2[]) // функция для поиска строки в строкe.
{
    int index;

    //index = strstr(str1, str2); // ищем вхождение строки 2 в строку 1

    for()
    {
        for()
        {

        }
    }

    return index; // возвращаем индекс
}

void print_str(int index) // функция вывода.
{
    index == NULL ? printf("str1 not in str2") : printf("str1 in str2, entry index is: %d", index); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i=0; str1[i]!='\0'; i++) {
   for(j=i, k=0; str2[k]!='\0' && str1[j]==str2[k]; j++, k++)
      ;
   if(k>0 && str2[k]=='\0')
   {
      index = i;
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, всё работает, буду разбираться теперь получше что и как происходит, только вот вопрос: почему к примеру  если строка Hello а подстрока будет H то он говорит что не найдено? 0 индекс не проверяет походу

Comment: Сделай первоначальное значение index = -1 в функции find_str,  в функции же print_str сравнивай с -1

Comment: туплю что-то, написал так: в итоге косяк - и везде кроме первого пишет что не входит в строку.

`int find_str(char str1[], char str2[])
{
 int i, j, k, index = -1;
 
 for(i = 0; str1[i]!= '\0'; i++) 
 {
  for(j = i, k = 0; str2[k]!= '\0' && str1[j] == str2[k]; j++, k++);
  {
   if(k > 0 && str2[k] == '\0')
    index = i;
    break;
  }
 }
 return index; // возвращаем индекс
}

void print_str(int index) // функция вывода.
{
 index != -1 ? printf("str1 in str2, entry i is: %d", index) : printf("str1 not in str2"); 
}`

Comment: Ты пробовал выводить возвращаемое значение с find_str? Какое оно?

Comment: сейчас попробовал если в случаее с Hello введена подстрока H то возвращает 0, в остальных случаях - 1

Comment: У тебя проблема с  фигурными скобками в  if(k > 0 && str2[k] == '\0') index = i; break;. Посмотри чтобы они стояли после if, как у меня в примере

Comment: Ой невнимательность. незаметил этого просто, всё заработало как нужно, спасибо большое, буду дальше учиться))